# Show that a set $Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a zero set.

Tags: real-analysis

Definition of zero set: $Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a zero set if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable covering of $Z$ by open rectangles $S_k$ whose total area is less than $\epsilon$.

Show that a set $Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a zero set if and only if, for all $\epsilon >0$, there is a countable covering of $Z$ by open **squares** $Q_k$ whose total area is less than $\epsilon$.

The forward implication is very simple, Let Z be a zero set then there exist such rectangles and squares are rectangles done.

For the other direction I assume there are countable open squares covering Z with arbitrarily small area. So my thought is I can build one of the rectangles from the definition out of a finite number of these squares so that there will be countable number of rectangles with the same property. The problem I am having (assuming this is a correct approach) is that the rectangles can have arbitrary with, so how do I know just how many squares to use?

Comment: Actually writing it down is a little sticky, but every open rectangle is a union of finitely many open squares.

Comment: What is "total area"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't work with a fixed *number* of squares to cover each rectangle - you should work with a fixed *area*. For instance, if you can find a cover of any open rectangle by open squares such that the total area of the squares is no more than twice the area of the rectangle, you are done.

One way to do this is to cover the rectangle by a bunch of identical squares, where the side length of each square is the same as the smaller side length of the rectangle. You need to do a bit of work to deal with the fact that these are open rectangles and you need $n+1$ copies of a $1\times 1$ square to cover a $1\times n$ rectangle (except for $n=1$, where as single square suffices), but this gives that the total area of the cover no more than doubles. More generally, $\lceil x\rceil + 1$ copies of a $1\times 1$ square covers a $1\times x$ rectangle.